# Is it possible to adapt the width of a div that sticks to the left to always cover a div that is always centred?

Tags: jquery, css, html, sticky

I was able to do what I need to do with js, you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qgY98/7/), resize the window to see what I mean.

The code is:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var offset = $("#two").offset();
    $('#three').css('width',offset.left+320); 
});
```

The idea is that the red div is always "centered" but the part of the green div that overflows the read one (pointed with the arrow) is always the same:

[image]

But it doesn't look that that good when you resize it, is it possible to this with only css? Or modify the js so that it looks more fluid?

Comment: I have a solution, but it requires 2 divs for the green part.

Comment: Is the HTML structure set in stone?

Comment: @bbxdesign let's hear it! :)

Comment: @isherwood well, not really, but other parts of the site use the same method to centre divs, so it should react the same way, I don't know if I explain myself.

Comment: The green stuff must remain in a single div? If you can have two divs sharing that background then it would be quite easy to attach an absolutely-positioned DIV to the right side of the red one (and make the other have one 50% width)

Comment: @MichaelRobinson the red div moves fluently but the green one is jumpy when you resize.

Comment: @Trufa not on my system (Ubuntu) in Chrome or Firefox, works smoothly.

Comment: @OneTrickPony not at all, It could be as many divs as necessary.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson hmm interesting, this only seems to happen in chrome (win7), FF looks quite good.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson isn't that my question already?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if the green div may be absolutely positioned, then its outer width needs to be 50% + half of the red div's width + the fixed extra width you wanted (right of the red div):

```
#three{
    ...
    position: absolute;
    width:50%;
    padding-right:120px; /* half of 200 + 20 extra pixels */
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/qgY98/8/)

Comment: Hmm this is what I want, but I'm afraid I hadn't explain my question 100% correctly.  The problem is in my actual site see here http://i.imgur.com/s8vNONO.png I want "red div" would be the logo, and  I can't seem to make this solution work if what I'm trying to cover is from the middle to the left, am I correct? sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

With 2 divs, it's achievable.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/RP24h/

**HTML code**

```
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="red">
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
body{ padding-top:60px;}
div{ height:100px;}
#green{ background:green; position:absolute; left:0; top:60px; width:50%;}
#red{ background:red; width:400px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;}
#blue{ background:blue; position:absolute; right:-20px; top:0; width:20px;}
```

The idea here is that you position your **red** just as you would normally do, centered.
The **green** div is positioned in absolute and has a width of 50%, so it always starts at the left of your screen (with left:0;) and always ends at precisely the middle of the screen (with width:50%;). But because the **red** div is *always* centered, it hides the right end of the **green** div.

The **blue** div is here to add that extra you wanted. Just make sure that the right value is exactly the negative value of the width (here it's right:-20px; and width:20px;}. As a result, there will never be a gap between the red and blue divs, and the blue div will always be 20px large.